# What is the best way to represent scoring variables?

Tags: r

The data I got is like this:

```
Number  Age  Headache painful fatigue
1       43       5       2       3
1       45       3       3       3
1       46       6       5       2
2       66       1       0       3
2       67       1       4       5      
2       68       4       6       6
2       69       5       7       8
```

The same number refers to the same person. Scores in headache, painful and fatigue are from 0 to 10. Whtat's the best way to visualise/present the variation of the scores in each symptoms for all the patients in general? (better with the age parameter) Hope to generate the conclusion something like from the average age x to x_1, the scores of painful are increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to combine different Y scales (It makes the graph confusing.), so I would put the different response variables in their own plots.

Grouping observations that belong to the same person makes sense.

You could do something along these lines:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

df = data.frame(
  cbind(Number = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
    Age = c(43,45,46,66,67,68,69),
    Headache = c(5,3,6,1,1,4,5),
    painful = c(2,3,5,0,4,6,7),
    fatigue = c(3,3,2,3,5,6,8))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Number = factor(Number))

p1 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = Headache)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Number), scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()

p2 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = painful)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Number), scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()

p3 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = fatigue)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Number), scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()

plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)
```

[image: Vertically stacked line plots, faceted by 'Number']

Alternatively, if there are more Number cases, you could do this:

```
p1 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = Headache, group = Number, color = Number)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(40, 70, by = 5)) +
  theme_bw()

p2 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = painful, group = Number, color = Number)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(40, 70, by = 5)) +
  theme_bw()

p3 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = fatigue, group = Number, color = Number)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(40, 70, by = 5)) +
  theme_bw()

plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)
```

[image: Vertically stacked line plots, without facet on 'Number']

When you have a lot more patients, you could use box plots or density curves.